# QTAgent32 Holding File Open

Tags: c#

We're writting an app that will extract first text and then images from various files.

In our test scripts we are finding that once we have extracted the text and try to open the file for image extraction that the file is being held open by another process.

We have closed all references to the file, disposed them and set them to null.

Using Process Explorer we found that it was QTAgent32 that was holding it open.

How can we tell this library to release the handle or is this a known bug and it won't affect the production code?

Comment: Are you using QTAgent in your code, or is it some random, unaccociated process that happens to access those files?

Comment: What's QTAgent32's command line?

Comment: Not using QTAgent in our code.

Answer (score 3):

QTAgent32 is Visual Studio's test runner.

This means that your test has a `FileStream` that you forgot to close.

Comment: @SLaks, I just wrote a Windows app that calls our library and am still getting the same error.  Do you know why the test runner be running in this instance?

Comment: Do you have any unit tests? (if not, why not?)  Check QTAgent32's command line and parent process.

Comment: We have unit tests but they shouldn't be instantiated from the windows app calling the library surely?

Comment: No, but the tests are leaving the file open from the last time they were run.

Comment: I closed the library project, checked if anything was holding the file open and ran the windows application with the same result.  I get that the agent is the testing agent, now i'm wondering why it opens a file when I am importing the Release version of the library

Comment: Do you mean to say that the handle was only opened after you executed your project, without running any tests?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the tests in debug, pausing execution, and seeing what you break on. (There's a good answer somewhere on stackoverflow about this "poor man's profiling" technique).

I solved my instance of this problem this way. On the first try, I was surprised to see execution break on a call to [NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx). It was running on a background thread so the tests were still passing, but it was obviously not intended to be included in the tests. It was dead code anyway, so I completely removed it, restarted VS, and the tests are running smoothly again.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try when we come back to that project